# How to get the value of an element in figaro programming?

Tags: figaro-lang

How based on the value of an element one can return a value in a scala function?
That is, according to this piece of code, based on the value of the "Str" element, the value of the "Unseen" variable must be specified and return some value based on whether the value of the "Unseen" is true or false.

```
var Unseen =Apply(Str,(s:String)=> {
    var test = true
    var usBuffer = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
    for(t <- 0 to (T.length - 1)){
      usBuffer += S(s,Pair(pos.toString(),T(t)).toString())
    }

    for(k <- 0 to (usBuffer.length - 1)){
      if(usBuffer(k)!= 0){
        test = false
      }
    }
    if(test){
      true
    }
    else{
      false
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear.

Figaro models are composed of elements. To retrieve values from an element, you should run an inference algorithm on the model.

In the snippet above, you're applying a deterministic function to an element `Str`.

You could do something like

```
val p_false = VariableElimination.probability(unseen, false)
```

This would tell you the probability that `unseen` is false.

You could also do:

```
val ve = MPEVariableElimination()
ve.start()
ve.stop()
val most_likely_state = ve.mostLikelyValue(unseen)
```

Then `most_likely_state` will have be the value of `unseen` which is most probable given any evidence you've supplied to the model.

As an aside, it is a more idiomatic Scala style (and safer in practice) to use immutable `val`s instead of `var`s.